# Generar código QR para camaras ip

Tags: ip, cifrado

Quisiera realizar mi propia aplicación de cámaras de seguridad, pero no entiendo de qué forma generar el código QR que necesitan las cámaras IP chinas, las que le mostras el QR generado por app.

Esto es el código QR de la app "YCC365 Plus";

> **w'
> "jC<kbAG8U!jU9:SC%
> k'wU,AC&
> 0%rS
> #iQ9"hP8n
> C[M{E7D;c**

Eso genera, y no sé ni cómo generarlo y cómo decifrarlo.

Alguien tiene alguna data?